# Use date without time in database with ef

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-core

What class should I use to save a date (without time) with ef and asp.net core (using database postgres)? DateTimeOffset always tries to save a time.

```
public class something
{
        [Column(TypeName="date")]
        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;`?

Comment: I changed the datetimeoffset to DateTime and that seems to work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `StartDate` to be `DateTime`, rather than `DateTimeOffSet`:

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

You can then use `StartDate.Date` ([`DateTime.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTime.Date property.

```
StartDate.Date
```